# Rails Devise ajax registration json error handling

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ajax, devise

As a newbie in Rails, I stumbled upon a problem that I can't seem to figure out how to solve.

So I've been making an AJAX registration and everything works almost as I wanted, except for one thing. So when there are errors in registration I handle them like so:

```
    error: function(xhr) {
        var errors = jQuery.parseJSON(xhr.responseText).errors;
          for (messages in errors) {
            for (message in errors[messages]) {
                popup(message + " " + errors[messages][message], 'error');
              }
          }
    }
```

the output example is like this: **(This is what I want to change)**

```
- email has already been taken
- date_of_birth can't be blank
```

if I don't use AJAX the output becomes like this: **(This is what I want to get)**

```
- Email has already been taken
- Date of birth can't be blank
```

my `xhr.responseText` JSON data looks like this:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "email": {
            0: "has already been taken"
        },
        "date_of_birth": {
            0: "can't be blank"
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously I've been using the key for showing the output, but I could think of an alternative.

**My questions is:**
*How could I make my error output with AJAX show the same result as Devise outputs them by default?*

**UPDATE:**
This is my overridden Devise registrations controller:

```
class User::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  respond_to :json

  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :gender, :looking, :date_of_birth)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :current_password, :gender, :looking, :date_of_birth, :description)
  end

end
```

Comment: show us your controller code.